# How to use llvm to insert instructions?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

There are similar questions I found, but I am a complete newbie to llvm and I have a hard time understanding how llvm works. So what I want to write is a program that can print function call's return addresses of another C program right before it returns, it's equivalent to this.

```
int foo()
{
   printf("%p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
   return 0;
}
```

I wonder if llvm has such tools allowing me to do so? I looked into Module and BasicBlock, yet I did not find anything related to what I want to do.

Comment: You know you can [look at the llvm code which clang generates](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4_5baueboAhVelnIEHYrCDtQQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9148890%2Fhow-to-make-clang-compile-to-llvm-ir&usg=AOvVaw2FEspnx9Mr8gDtvZCJq728), right?  In my test it looks like `%1 = call i8* @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)`

Comment: Is there a way not to manually add the IR code? Like when the program is parsing and when it encounters a return statement,  "%1 = call i8* @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)" is automatically inserted ? Thanks !

Comment: You need to write a pass that will insert calls to this intrinsic. Starting documentation: http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html